# syntax error, unexpected kEND in active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, cancan

I'm setting up a working application on a new environment, and after running 'bundle install' I try to launch an application.
And I get a following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (compile error
D:/Dev_apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:85: syntax error, unexpected kEND
D:/Dev_apps/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc5/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/read.rb:87: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND):
6:   <nav class="round">
7: 
8:     <ul>
9:       <% if can? :browse_backend, current_user %>
10:         <li><%= link_to "Админка", admin_root_path %></li>
11:       <% end %>
12: 
app/models/user.rb:60:in `has_role?'
app/models/ability.rb:14:in `initialize'
app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb:9:in   `_app_views_layouts__header_html_erb___239100443_122539296'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:16:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__144136837_122749020'
```

What I can't understand is how can that happen in a gem.

Comment: Did you change anything in read.rb? This typically means there is a syntax error in read.rb

Comment: Does it work with English characters instead of "Админка"? I've had problems in the past with encoding.

Comment: Just did `> rails new Test` , added one `g scaffold Product title:string price:float`, tried to launch - static "Welcome aboard" page loads well, but if I try to access localhost:3000/products - the same `attribute_methods/read.rb:85: syntax error, unexpected kEND` still here

Comment: Sometimes, that Test application would give a "wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)" on Product.all, Setting up mysql2 of version 0.3.6 fixed an issue (I was running on 0.3.2 before) I don't know why, frankly. It fixed my initial problem, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this error when I upgraded my app to rails 3.1 and I was able to fix it by installing a more recent version of the mysql2 gem (I installed 0.3.7).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your code but since the gems use your code to do their magic it seems like the error comes from the gem.

Check your user.rb file at line 60. You might have a syntax error around there.